# ¿Cómo encontrar en valor mas próximo a 0 en un objeto?

Tags: javascript

Deseo encontrar el valor de un  key mas próximo a 0 en un objeto dado. Se debe tener en cuenta que el valor a buscar puede se negativo, es est6e caso debería dar como resultado el key y su valor correspondiente: "9":-1.3 , luego este debería eliminarse para comenzar la siguiente búsqueda que debería ser el siguiente numero mas próximo a 0, en este caso correspondería: "7":1.3 ,para luego eliminarlo del mismo objeto y seguir el proceso hasta que el objeto quede vacío.
Muchas gracias.

```
var nunFinales = { 0: 1.6, 2: 49, 7: 1.3, 9: -1.3 }
```

Se diría que se podría simplemente organizar el objeto por el valor de cada key, y luego eliminar cada elemento secuencialmente, pero el inconveniente es la presencia de números negativos.

Cuando se presenten que tengan la misma diferencia como: "7":1.3 y "9":-1.3  se debería dar prioridad al que tenga menor key "7":1.3 .

Cualquier faltante en la pregunta comentar.

Comment: Interesante, podrías mostrarnos que has hecho,consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: He buscado muchas opciones pero todas han sido con números positivos y solo en arrays

Comment: Podría crear una función que me genere la cantidad de valores que me indique el valor de cada key, pero el otro inconveniente es que hay decimales que se podrían multiplicar por 10 para volverlos enteros. es una idea.

Comment: La otra seria separar los números negativos y positivos, todos dejarlos como positivos y luego si ordenarlos, creo es lo mas factible.

Comment: Entre 0 y n hay un delta definido por abs(0-n) por lo tanto este será el valor mas cercano luego esa diferencia deberás pasarla a una variable auxiliar, luego esa variable compararla con el siguiente valor y si es menor que la siguiente entonces la siguiente es tu valor mas cercano de lo contrario la anterior lo sigue siendo.

Comment: Dices que la key "9" está mas próxima a 0 que la key "7" siendo que ambas están a la misma distancia. Por otro lado, no especificas muy bien esto de organizar el objeto por valor de cada key. Recuerda que un objeto no se organiza, simplemente se accede mediante keys, ahora si fuera un array si podriamos hablar de organizar. Tu quieres eliminar cada key de forma ordenada para luego tener un objeto vacío. Pero como no indicas qué hacer en medio, básicamente la funcion que pides devuelve un objeto vacio: `foo() { return {} }` <- esto cumpliría con los requerimiento. Por favor detalla más.

Comment: Si tienes toda la razón, mi objetivo es poder asignar  cada uno de estos valores pero tengo que estar seguro que no falte ninguno.

Comment: Editare la pregunta teniendo en cuenta su sugerencia

Comment: Posible solución: Obtener un arreglo con [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) para recorrer y crear un nuevo arreglo, donde cada elemento sea `[key, valorReal + valorAbsoluto]` para dar menor "peso" a los negativos; ordenas el arreglo resultante y en la primera posición tendrás `[claveParaEliminar, valorMasCercanoACero]`

Comment: lo experimentare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente no recomiendo eliminar elementos de un objeto, pero creo que la siguiente implementación te puede ayudar a lograr lo que quieres (sin eliminar datos)

```js
const numFinales = { 0: 1.6, 2: 49, 7: 1.3, 9: -1.3 };

const sortedNumbers = Object.entries(numFinales)
  .sort((a, b) => {
    const [aKey, aValue] = a;
    const [bKey, bValue] = b;

    return Math.abs(aValue) - Math.abs(bValue);
  });

sortedNumbers.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log({ key, value });
})
```

En esta implementación utilizamos la ayuda de `Object.entries` que nos facilita convertir una llave valor en un arreglo de tuplas `llave - valor`, con esto podemos ordenar el arreglo resultante utilizando `sort` y a este le aplicamos una función específica acorde a la lógica que necesitas, donde ordenamos los números de menor a mayor según su cercanía al 0, esto cubre también los casos donde el número sea negativo.

**Eliminando datos:**

Como alternativa, si en verdad requires borrar los elementos que vas encontrando puedes añadir esta sección de código:

```js
sortedNumbers.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log({ key, value });

  // Borrar cada elemento una vez mostrado
  delete numFinales[key];
});

console.log({ numFinales })
```

Y el resultado final aplicando lo anterior queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
const numFinales = { 0: 1.6, 2: 49, 7: 1.3, 9: -1.3 };

const sortedNumbers = Object.entries(numFinales)
  .sort((a, b) => {
    const [aKey, aValue] = a;
    const [bKey, bValue] = b;

    return Math.abs(aValue) - Math.abs(bValue);
  });

sortedNumbers.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log({ key, value });

  // Borrar cada elemento una vez mostrado
  delete numFinales[key];
});

console.log({ numFinales })
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pensé que iba a ser mas difícil, estoy aprendiendo

Comment: ¿hay la posibilidad de realizar la misma operación sin el forEach?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un `for` tradicional o un `for of`